# Extract part of a column using regex or split in python

Tags: python, regex, pandas, split

Hello I have a df such as

```
COL1   COL2
G1     QANH010008.1:18255-18820(-):Hab_ob
G1     QANH010002:7-10(-):Hab_ob
```

and I would like to create 2 new `COL3` and `COL4` where i put the number before the first `-` and after the first `-`

Here the ouptut should be

```
COL1   COL2                                COL3   COL4
G1     QANH010008.1:18255-18820(+):Hab_ob  18255  18820
G1     QANH010002:7-10(-):Hab_ob           7      10
```

Answer (score 2):

You can used named capturing groups for this then join to the original DataFrame. This answer incorporates a couple of suggestions from @MarkWang.

```
df.join(df['COL2'].str.extract(r'(?P<COL3>\d+)\-(?P<COL4>\d+)'))
```

Output:

```
Out[206]: 
  COL1                                COL2   COL3   COL4
0   G1  QANH010008.1:18255-18820(-):Hab_ob  18255  18820
1   G1           QANH010002:7-10(-):Hab_ob      7     10
```

Comment: Good approach, in particular the `?P` part. Two comments,(1) expand=True should be default I guess, (2) would use 'df.join(df['COL2'].str.extract)' rather than pd.concat to save some space

Comment: @MarkWang: updated answer taking into account your suggestions. Much shorter now! Thank you :)